# IE borders breaking navigation

Tags: css, internet-explorer

another issue in IE 6... [link](http://plwd.co.uk/rangers)

The navbar link list has a border applied to the left side of each element.

In fireforx/safari this matches up with the navbar background but in IE the border/element spills out below the navbar ( the border sticks out the bottom).

EDIT: ALSO, the navbar is the entire length of the blue header in IE, when it should only be as big as the navigations links inside it! arg!

Any ideas? thanks.

Pictures:

How it looks in ie6:

[ie6 sucking http://plwd.co.uk/rangers/images/ie6.jpg](http://plwd.co.uk/rangers/images/ie6.jpg)

How it should look:

[alt text http://plwd.co.uk/rangers/images/firefox.jpg](http://plwd.co.uk/rangers/images/firefox.jpg)

Comment: It actually looks fine in IE 7 - are you using IE 6?

Comment: IE 6 stinks, by the way - I am dealing with major issues with it right now because we have to support it as well as IE 7. Barf!

Comment: ok I'm bringin the conversation back here so Nakkisormi can delete his answer. IE7 does look fine, IE6 is the stinker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try getting rid of the height rule on the anchor tags, and using top/bottom margins/paddings to ensure they fill the space.  I find CSS using floats a lot easier when you don't try to enforce heights on elements.

Comment: your absolutely right Chris.

I had a height set for the link element which IE6 ignored but other browsers used to crop the borders.

I replaced the height:26 with a margin-bottom:-4 and this had the same effect, but worked in all browsers.

thanks for your help.

Comment: Also, the extra long navbar was fixed by floating the div for the rounded corner to the left.

Case closed

Comment: glad it worked.  I didn't have IE6 installed to try it out, but I suspected as much.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the borders doing it - it's the line-height. Your nav anchors are inheriting "line-height: 2em" from #header.  Try setting the line height on the anchors (or their parent LI's or the UL) to something smaller - maybe 1.5em or so - and then make up the difference with some top padding on the anchors

Comment: Thanks Andy,
I'd already got it to work as i described above, but it's worth taking a look at what you've said too.